# Typescript strange result of declaration file

Tags: angular, typescript

**any.ts:**

```
legend = (value) => {
    return typeof value === 'boolean' ?
        {
            'options.legend.display': value
        } :
        {
            'options.legned.display' : true,
            'options.legend.position': value
        };
};
```

}

**any.d.ts**:

```
legend: (value: any) => {
    'options.legend.display': boolean;
    options.legned.display?: undefined;
    options.legend.position?: undefined;
} | {
    'options.legned.display': boolean;
    'options.legend.position': any;
    options.legend.display?: undefined;
};
```

*.d.ts files occurred error

why compiler does not use quote?, am i used wrong syntax?

---

below codes work fine :(

**any.d.ts (edited by myself)**

```
legend: (value: any) => {
    'options.legend.display': boolean;
    'options.legned.display'?: undefined;
    'options.legend.position'?: undefined;
} | {
    'options.legned.display': boolean;
    'options.legend.position': any;
    'options.legend.display'?: undefined;
};
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: error TS1131: Property or signature expected.

error TS1005: ';' expected.

Comment: At which line is the error?

Comment: started at 3rd line, because of quote unlike 2nd line

Answer (score 0):

If you use dots in property names, you must use them as string and access them with square bracket notation, not dod notation.

Why, you ask?

Well, take your example, you've got a `legend` object with a property `options.legend.display`. Now imagine you add another property called `options`, with another called `legend`. So, when you write this:

```
legend.options.legend.display = '';
```

What property are you setting? This can't be ambiguous, so, by writing this, you're telling that you're setting the property `display` of the object at property `legend` in the property `options` of the object called `legend`.

If you want to access the property with dots, you need to write:

```
legend['options.legend.display'] = '';
```

And if you want to access nested properties with square bracket notation:

```
legend['options']['legend']['display'] = '';
```

Got it?

Comment: thanks your comments, but I'm not saying that.

i just need object key and value as like map, and key may has dot.

Comment: You are asking why you're getting an error, aren't you? I explained why. I also explained what you have to do if you want to use dots on the name of your properties (or keys)

Comment: as i known. object key can have any string and number. and that object does not use with human typing

Comment: Yes, it can. But to access it you must use bracket notation, and to declare it you must enclose it in quotes

Comment: That is not my codes. Typescript compiler made it with error

Comment: Aaah. Well, sorry. but that wasn't clear in your post. I thought it was your code.

Comment: :/ Easy misconceptions to make. Most of the OPs questions are unclear / lack effort.